# How to let all worker do same task in dask?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I want to let all workers do same task ,like this:

```
from dask import distributed
from distributed import Client,LocalCluster
import dask
import socket


def writer(filename,data):
    with open(filename,'w') as f:
        f.writelines(data)

def get_ip(x):
    return socket.gethostname()
    #writer('/data/1.txt',a)
client = Client('192.168.123.1:8786')

A=client.submit(get_ip, 0,workers=['w1','w2'], pure=False)
print(client.ncores(),
        client.scheduler_info()
#       dask.config.get('distributed')
     )
A.result()
```

i have 2 workers,but just print 1 workers'hostname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to achieve what you want is to use the Client.run method

```
client.run(socket.gethostname)
```

This runs the function on all workers and returns all results.  It does not use the normal task scheduling system, which is designed for a very different purpose from what you want.

Comment: workres remind me : `Run out-of-band function 'get_ip'`,i have a complicated compution by pandas,can i use it in producation envs? such as --memory-limit parameters  is valid?